# carousel with 6 to 8 divs stacked vertically/ horizontally (room layout) controlling the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a slider that is controlled by a static boxes on the left (vertically and horizontally) like a room layout,.
Clicking on each of the box will show an image in the carousel / slider . So in short boxes controls what images will be displayed. nothing fancy but the image will have fade effect on the main box. I am trying to achieve this by using jquery. But i am not sure where to start.
For illustration i am attaching the visual. Any pointers / or guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks[image: example of output shown below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this for you, it's 3 infinite carousels, positioned and sized accordlingly to create a layout with all the different functionalities working. It'll give you a good start on what you wish to achieve.

Built on from the example provided: http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyIW/eg8f3a0b/

If you wish for the user to do anything via a click inside the JS add

```
object.onclick=function(){myScript};
```

where object is the element the user would be required to click, and my script is where you will place your javascript. So where you wish to control the image movement change the function call to an onclick method, change the element name to that box and inside the script dictate where to change the image.

This should help you (right and left button control): http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-infinite-carousel-with-nice-features/

with the code i've provided for you, if you wish for the carousel to have a change when the user hovers.

Create a `<div>` element around each `<ul>`. Give it an id and change the `div:hover {}` attribute in CSS.

Example for one infinite fade carousel:

HTML:

```
<div id="slide_con">
    <ul class="slider">
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
slider {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 500px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 150px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider li {
  display:block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}
```

JS:

```
// settings
var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

function slides(){
  return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
$interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
);
```

This code was taken from: http://paulmason.name/item/simple-jquery-carousel-slider-tutorial

if you want to make it responsive, change the width of `ul` from `px` to `%`

I know this doesn't show everything you need, but it's a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am trying to understand, But i think my requirement is that when a user  clicks one of the boxes on the left side the image is shown in the carousel (blue window in the diagram), i don't need infinite looping.May be I misunderstood. or i was probably not clear.

Comment: No you was clear but I didn't want to build the whole program for you, use the links I've provided you to alter the code in the fashion you want it. I provided you with enough material to build what you need. Infinite merely means it isn't controlled by buttons, I provided a link that will tell you how to integrate buttons. I've provided a jsfiddle that will help you with implement multiple carousels or one carousel with the example provided, if you combine both pieces of material you'll get what you require.  The CSS is just positioning and assigning width and height to the elements.

Comment: The on click method will allow the user to click a div you assign and when that method is clicked move image over to which way you want it as the ul width is the size of one image, the rest of the images are hidden the link regarding buttons will give you the answers for that

Comment: Ok, Thanks, for the information. I'll try to connect the pieces.

Comment: if you have any trouble with anything, let me know

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for all the tips. I have connected the dots and the fiddle is available over here. It's not the cleanest.
Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/aryanc/eznkr3gb/

Comment: Just wanted to ask , in continuation of above question,
If the blue images (referring to my diagram above) were to be on top of an already exiting slider. so what i mean is that once you hover over on the  room layout boxes the images will slide out (blue box) and would overlay on an "already  existing slider " that have some rotating images. what would be the best way to achieve that. 
I mean the hovering over images fast will have the slide out affect , but i guess that would be funny looking.

Thanks.

Comment: you'll need to look at :hover in CSS3, I don't really understand what your end game is with this question, but look more into that and i'm sure it'll click for you.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry if i was not clear. I want the images according to the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/aryanc/eznkr3gb/ in the slider (right hand side)  to slide out rather than fade in or fade out , when a user hover over the smaller images on the left hand side (thumbnails).
Initially there will not be any slide outs , only on hover on thumbnails, and the slide out will be on an overlay on an already existing content region.